# Stationary Distribution of Ehrenfest Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The example in my book for an Ehrenfest Markov chain is:
A system of of two urns, A & B where there are 2n balls total in both urns. We are assuming that there are $i$ balls in urn A and $2n - i$ balls in urn B at any instant.

How do you find the stationary distribution of the Ehrenfest Markov Chain? I know that the definition of a stationary distribution is as follows:

$\pi P = \pi$

Where $\pi$ is an eigenvector of the transition probability matrix whose associated eigenvalue is equal to 1. I also know that the TPM comes from the following:

$P_{ij} =\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{i}{2n} & if j=i-1 \\
      1-\frac{i}{2n} & if j=i+1 \\
      0 & otherwise\\
\end{array} 
\right.$

I have also seen that the stationary distribution is $\binom{2n}{i} 2^{-2n}$

Would someone be able to help come to this conclusion that the stationary distribution is above?

Thank you!

Comment: The equation $\pi P = \pi$ gives you a recurrence equation for $\pi(i)$, $i = 0, \dots, 2n$, which you can solve to get the desired result. Or you can say that indeed, the distribution that you give solves this equation, and since the stationary distribution is unique, then it is the right one.